# Removing Non-printable character from column

Tags: shell, unix, unicode

I have file as below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to remove non printable characters from in between line.
Can anyone help me on this?

I used below command but it is removing non printable character from whole file

tr -dc '[:print:]\n\r' < Sample_file_excel.csv >

column 1,column 2,column 3,column 4,column 5,column 6,column 7,column 8,column 9,column 10
12310,42324564756,"a simple string with a , comma","string with or,without,commas",string 1,USD,12,70%,8/1/2013
23455,12312255564,"string, with, multiple, commas","string with or, without commas",string 2,USD,433,70%,7/15/2013
23525,74535243123,"string , with commas,

and - hypens and: semicolans","string with or, without commas",string 1,CAND,744,70%,5/6/2013
46476,15467534544,"lengthy string, with commas

, multiple: colans","string with or, without commas",string 2,CAND,388,70%,9/21/2013
12310,42324564756,"a simple string with a , comma","string with or,without,commas",string 1,USD,12,70%,8/1/2013
23455,12312255564,"string, with, multiple, commas","string with or, without commas",string 2,USD,433,70%,7/15/2013
23525,74535243123,"string , with commas,

and - hypens and: semicolans","string with or, without commas",string 1,CAND,744,70%,5/6/2013  46476,15467534544,"lengthy string, with commas

, multiple: colans","string with or, without commas",string 2,CAND,388,70%,9/21/2013

Output Should be like this:

column 1,column 2,column 3,column 4,column 5,column 6,column 7,column 8,column 9,column 10
12310,42324564756,"a simple string with a , comma","string with or,without,commas",string 1,USD,12,70%,8/1/2013
23455,12312255564,"string, with, multiple, commas","string with or, without commas",string 2,USD,433,70%,7/15/2013
23525,74535243123,"string , with commas,and - hypens and: semicolans","string with or, without commas",string 1,CAND,744,70%,5/6/2013
46476,15467534544,"lengthy string, with commas, multiple: colans","string with or, without commas",string 2,CAND,388,70%,9/21/2013
12310,42324564756,"a simple string with a , comma","string with or,without,commas",string 1,USD,12,70%,8/1/2013
23455,12312255564,"string, with, multiple, commas","string with or, without commas",string 2,USD,433,70%,7/15/2013
23525,74535243123,"string , with commas and - hypens and: semicolans","string with or, without commas",string 1,CAND,744,70%,5/6/2013
46476,15467534544,"lengthy string, with commas, multiple: colans","string with or, without commas",string 2,CAND,388,70%,9/21/2013

Answer (score 0):

Making a test file with `\r`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","; print "a","x\ry","c"}' > file
$ hexdump -C file
00000000  61 2c 78 0d 79 2c 63 0a                           |a,x.y,c.|
```

Removing non-printables from `$2` and `$3`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="," }                 # set comma as separator
{
    for(i=2;i<=3;i++)            # fields 2 and 3
        gsub(/[^[:print:]]/,"")  # replace all non-printables with ""
}1' file                         # print
a,xy,c
```

Comment: Replace `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) ` with `for(i=2;i<=3;i++)` for keeping fields >3 unchanged.

Comment: @WalterA Thanks, that was a lapse.

Comment: getting same result:


$ awk '
> BEGIN { FS="," }                 # set comma as separator
> {
>     for(i=2;i<=3;i++)            # fields 2 and 3
>         gsub(/[:print:]/,"")  # replace all non-printables with ""
> }1' Sample_file_excel.csv
S.No,Name,ComayName,,,
1,ABCD¶S,CLH¶,,,
2,DEF¶Roy,Exs,,,
3,¶Viv Roy,Wo,,,

Comment: Well, I guess the chars are printable after all. Really can't tell based on a pic.

Comment: @JamesBrown I have added actual text file. Please help.

Comment: @JamesBrown : Please help

Comment: Please fix the data in the question first, use the `{}` button to format the data. That's a mess.